# Google Earth Engine CHIRPS Data, Problem with Visualisation

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I want to load Precipitaion Data for my region. But when I ran the code, just the global South beneath Germany appears. Can you help?

https://code.earthengine.google.com/?accept_repo=users/laraemsinghoff/Start

```
var styling2 = {color: 'red', fillColor: '00000000'};
Map.addLayer (Westfalen.style(styling2));
Map.centerObject (Westfalen)

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('UCSB-CHG/CHIRPS/DAILY')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2018-03-01', '2021-10-01'))
                  .filterBounds (Westfalen);
var precipitation = dataset.select('precipitation');
var precipitationVis = {
  min: 1.0,
  max: 17.0,
  palette: ['001137', '0aab1e', 'e7eb05', 'ff4a2d', 'e90000'],
};

Map.addLayer(precipitation, precipitationVis, 'Precipitation');
```

Comment: The link is not showing any code

Comment: https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Flaraemsinghoff%2FStart%3ACHIRSP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the reference that appears in the citations tab of the CHIRPS dataset (https://www.nature.com/articles/sdata201566), the data is "quasi-global (50°S-50°N)", so that is the reason why there is no data north of 50°N.

Comment: Thats bad. Thanks for ponting out.

Comment: Is there any alternative?

Comment: You could take a look at the precipitation datasets already available in GEE to see if there's one that fits your requirements: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/tags/precipitation. My first thought was using TRMM as an alternative, but it has the same global coverage as CHIRPS.